# Could an unlevel furnace be causing noise from the blower fan?

Tags: hvac

The blower fan on my gas furnace sounds like it is hitting other metal when it turns on or off. I had it serviced and he replaced the blower run cap but it has started again after about a week.

Could it be the furnace is not level? The service man said no that wouldn't do it but that's what it sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it could be, but probably isn't. A spinning fan will hit anything in its path regardless of the relative direction of gravity.

I'd recommend calling your service person again for further troubleshooting.